# Samsung SCX3405 MFP scanner not detected since upgrading to 20.04LTS. Printing function works. PC is HP8300

Tags: scanner

Have not been able to find suitable information with clear step by step explanations,
I can copy and paste into terminal but not familiar with Linux commands.

Comment: Thanks all ok up to finding the printer details. Clicking on settings then printer details  I have http://Samsung SCX-3400 Series (SEC30CDA72AEA88)._ipp._tcp.local:631.

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung SCX-3405 is actually a device made by HP. To get the scanner working, you'll probably need to do a couple of things:

1. Download the driver from HP
2. Manually edit your `xerox_mfp.conf` (don't worry about the `xerox` bit) to include a record for your scanner.

**1 — Download the Driver from HP**

If you haven't already installed the necessary driver for this printer, follow these steps. If the driver has already been installed, skip to the next section.

1. Visit [HP's printer driver support page](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/printers)
2. Search for for: SCX-3405W
   ***Note:** If no results are returned, be sure to change the OS to "Linux" and "Ubuntu"*
   You should now see a page that looks like this:

   [image: Get Some HP Drivers]
3. Download the driver file
4. Open Terminal (if it's not already open) and verify that you're in the Downloads directory:

   ```
   $ cd ~/Downloads
   ```
5. Expand the file

   ```
   tar -zxvf uld_V1.00.39_01.17.tar.gz
   ```
6. Enter the new directory and install the driver:

   ```
   $ cd uld
   $ sudo ./install.sh
   ```

As an optional step, check to see if your scanner is detected after installing these drivers. If it is, then you needn't do the next section.

**2 — Configure the Scanner**

These steps assume that your SCX-3405 is operating independently on the network and not connected directly to your computer via USB:

1. Find the IP address of your printer by:
   • Opening Settings
   • Clicking on "Printers"
   • Clicking the gear icon for the Samsung
   • Choosing "Printer details"

   This will open a modal form that will show the address of your printer, which will look something like `192.168.0.175`
2. Edit the `xerox_mfp.conf` with `sudo`:

   ```
   $ sudo vi /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf
   ```

   ***Note:** Use whichever text editor you are most comfortable with. It does not need to be* `vi`. *This is more muscle memory than an endorsement.*
3. Add this to the bottom of the file:

   ```
   # Samsung SCX-3405W, network mode
   # tcp HOST_ADDR PORT
   tcp 192.168.0.175 9400
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to replace* `192.168.0.175` *with the actual IP address of your printer, otherwise this will not work.*
4. Save the file
   ⇢ If you're using `vi`, this can be done by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then <kbd>W</kbd> to **W**rite, and <kbd>Q</kbd> to **Q**uit.
5. Check to see if your scanner is detected. *Sometimes* it is necessary to log out and log back in before the scanner is seen, and sometimes it is not.

Hopefully, after all of this effort, you are able to see the scanner and use it properly